# How to position DIV within Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to have `3 x 340px` wide boxes (used for holding social media feeds) next to each other. I've got `the first 2 lined up` perfectly but `the 3rd is not lining up`.

I'm using a custom `html` field in `wordpress`. Code is below:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;float:center;">

<div style="width:340px;height:500px;float:left;background-color:red;">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/consciousyouthuk" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/consciousyouthuk" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/consciousyouthuk">Conscious Youth C.I.C</a></blockquote></div></div>

<div style="margin:0 auto;width:340px;height:500px;background-color:red;">

<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="340" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/Cyouthcic?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script></div>

<div style="width:340px;height:500px;float:right;background-color:red;">

</div>

</div>
```

Image here shows what it's doing:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: If the 100% width of the parent wrapper is less than 1020px your 3rd float will wrap beneath the first two.

Comment: There is no float:center. All the divs should have float:left on them. You should also you should probably be using percentages and not pixels as widths i.e. 33.3%.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this easily by using bootstrap grid. check the jsfiddle output  :: https://jsfiddle.net/ruokr7rp/1/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:red;">



      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      </script>
      <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/consciousyouthuk" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false">
        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/consciousyouthuk" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/consciousyouthuk">Conscious Youth C.I.C</a></blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:red;">


      <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="340" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/Cyouthcic?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a>
      <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </div>


    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:red;">



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

check this :: https://jsfiddle.net/ruokr7rp/